# Row_Count with date and reset count with name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following data

```
11/10/2011  john Maths
12/10/2011  Max  Geometry
11/10/2011  John Geometry
12/10/2011  Max  Maths
```

So I want the following result

```
1 11/10/2011  john Maths
2 12/10/2011  John Geometry
1 11/10/2011  Max  Geometry
2 12/10/2011  John Geometry
```

Comment: And **how** do you get to this result?? What are the criteria to sort it??? Not clear at all - you need to provide more relevant info!

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by [name] order by [date] asc, [subject] asc) as row,
    [date],
    [name],
    [subject]
from table_name
```

Read more about [`row_number()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is `row_number() over (partition by name, order by name)`

Add this clause to your simple querying of students.